# How to make Batch apex query locator with parameter from invocableMethod (Flow)?

Tags: batch

I want to create a flow that calls the apex class using batch, because i have a huge data that if i only using flow i will get limitation. so i think i should call an apex class that use batch to run my query.

how to make apex batch receive parameters from InvocableMethod? anyone have any idea about it? it means alot, thankyou so much

This is my code now, but i always get qliVal null

```
global class UT_FSL_Recalculate_Total implements Database.Batchable <sObject>,Database.Stateful{
    
    @InvocableMethod(label = 'Quote ID')
    global static void listQuotes(List<QuoteLineItem> qliVal){
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(new UT_FSL_Recalculate_Total(qliVal));
    }
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext info){
        String SOQL = '';
        SOQL = 'SELECT Id,Recalculate_Total__c,Price_is_Retrieved__c FROM QuoteLineItem';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(SOQL);
        //should we use queryloc start? because value of id is from invocable?
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<QuoteLineItem> listQli){
        //logic here
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info){ 
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Invokable methods require invokable variables. Use an approach similar to [this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_flow_custom_property_editor_sobject_action_example). Additionally, you likely want to include reference to (using a binding) the batch's list of quote line items in the SOQL query defined in `start`. Finally, there is no need to use `global` for any of the methods or the class unless you are needing it to be visible across a namespace boundary.

Comment: Hy @PhilW Thankyou for the answer, but i still confused about it, if u dont mind can you give an explaination in my code? or give my an example about it? i already read and looking in many article but still cannot figure it out. Thankyou so much

Comment: Try starting with the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-explore-the-automation-comps-sample-app/get-to-know-automation-comps) that covers invokable actions. You need to use the `@InvocableVariable` annotation to allow data to be received from the flow. Having just a list of SObject records of any type (including generically as `SObject`) doesn't work. Try doing this training before coming back here and providing your own answer! I am sure you will get it if you do the exercises.